# How to make a cross referenced heading number with a customized numbered outline without first level number?

Tags: microsoft-word, headers, cross-reference, numbering

I've made an "Appendix" heading style using the style Heading 5 as the base style.  I want the numbers to show up as "Appendix A" so the "Customized Updated Numbered List" is set with the formatting number: "Appendix " then including the level number from Level 6 and a link to Heading Level 5 [image: image of setup] The headings show up numbered correctly, but the cross references do not.

As an example, say I have sections from Heading 1, then an Appendix.  If I reference the heading number to either of the first two sections they show up correctly.  But if I reference the number for the appendix, instead of showing up as "Appendix A" it shows up as "2Appendix A" [image: image of the problem]  For some reason it always has the number of the preceding section stuck up front.  I cannot figure out why that is happening.  I appreciate any help.  Thank you!

Here is a [OneDrive link to the file](https://1drv.ms/w/s!Al4VhsV8njjB1FiRfuBckJgPZEKs?e=qDKLZx).

(I'm using MS word for Mac Version 16.61 on macOS Monterey 12.2.1)

Comment: Hi Ben, have you looked at http://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numberingappendixes.html. It looks like you have. Consider saving a sample with the problem on DropBox or OneDrive and posting a view link here in your question.

Comment: Charles, I did not see shaunakelly's page exactly, but something along those lines.  Thank you for the reference.  Here is a [link](https://1drv.ms/w/s!Al4VhsV8njjB1FiRfuBckJgPZEKs?e=qDKLZx) to the file.  I will also add it as an edit to the post.  Thank you!

Comment: Ben, when I update the TOC I do not see any number preceding Appendix A.